# Entering form data into database through php using wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to put data from the form to the MySQL database of the wamp server using PHP. I did all and "failed" is displayed on the screen after pressing the submit button.

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php

    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'bse3a');

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $fName = $_POST['first_name'];
        $lName = $_POST['last_name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password= $_POST['password'];
        $rPassword= $_POST['re_password'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone_number'];
        $dob = $_POST['birth_date'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];

        $query = "insert into  students(fName,lName,email,password,rPassword,phone,dob,gender) values ('$fName', '$lName', '$email', '$password', '$rPassword', '$phone', '$dob', '$gender')";

        if(mysqli_query($con,$query)){
            echo "Register successfully";
        }
        else {
            echo "failed";
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: You're only connecting to the database but you're not making any queries at all. `$query` is just an ordinary PHP-string so when you do `if ($query)`, it will always evaluate as true (since the string isn't empty). To actually do the query, you need to use [mysqli_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) I would recommend you going through some PHP + MySQL tutorials. I would also suggest using PDO instead of MySQLi. It has a bit more verbose API which makes it easier to use.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use completely unescaped user data directly in your queries either, or you will be wide open for [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks. You should read up on using Prepared Statements with placeholders. You can use that with both MySQLi and PDO.

Comment: Yes.. I use mysqli_connect() which works. But now it display "failed"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show SQL error in PHP custom mysqli function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737500/how-to-show-sql-error-in-php-custom-mysqli-function)

Comment: _**Never ever** ever never_ store passwords in plain text! You should _always_ hash the passwords using [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and only store the hashes. Then you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash. There's also no reason for having the column `rPassword` in your database. The "repeat password" field is basically just for validating the password (to make sure the user didn't made a typo in the first password input)

Answer (score 1):

While there's not enough information to debug your case, you should display that last error to understand why it doesn't work.

```
//in fail case
echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($con));
```

Then update your question.